# How to Split one row data to many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert the following Data in table A  and to make trigger for the inserted date to split in many rows in table B depend on the data  in table A

For Example
 Table A have the following Data :

```
Name    Start_Date      Totals  No_Payment    Diff_Date
Dave    1/10/17          10000        5           7
```

the Data to split into Table A for 5 Row depend on No_Payment column  and add 7 days to Start_Date      based on Diff_Date column  .

Thank you

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also the expected result.

Comment: Recursive CTE comes to mind

Comment: Probably best to create a Service Broker solution, to call a stored procedure and insert the multiple rows into the second table, this would run Asynchronously and would not lock the initial table whilst running the recursive loop to insert the multiple rows in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement, re explain it.

```
declare @t table(Name varchar(50),  Start_Date date,Totals int, No_Payment int,Diff_Date int)
insert into @t values ('Dave','1/10/17',  10000 , 5, 7)
create table #num(num int)
insert into #num
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by number) from master..spt_values

--select * from #num
SELECT *
    ,NewStartDate
    ,DATEADD(day, t.Diff_Date, NewStartDate) RequireStartDate
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(day, num, t.Start_Date) NewStartDate
    FROM #num
    WHERE num <= t.No_Payment
    ) c


drop table #num
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, if you did something like (num-1)*7 in the DATEADD then the first record would go in with the original start date and the following records would have the weekly increments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution.

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(10), Start_Date datetime,Totals int,No_Payment int,Diff_Date int)
insert @t 
values ('Dave','1/10/17',10000,5,7),
       ('JOHN','2/10/17',10001,2,5),
       ('Fotos','3/10/17',10002,3,4),
       ('Manchi','7/10/17',10003,4,6)

select * from @t;

--Insert into <YOUR TABLE>
select t.Name
       , DATEADD(day,t.Diff_Date, t.Start_Date) as Start_Date
       ,t.Totals
       ,t.No_Payment
       ,t.Diff_Date
from   @t t
join   master..spt_values n
       on n.type = 'P'
       and n.number < convert(int,No_Payment,1)
```

It's working in SQLServer-2014.

Comment: Thank you but the start_Date should be change by adding 5 days for each row

Comment: If you don't want to change start_date based on Diff_Date means... just change this line like this,

DATEADD(day,5, t.Start_Date) as Start_Date